# Using PHP to loop through values in a POST request

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach, http-post

I have a form that allows people to enter a keyword.

I'm wanting people to be able to add one keyword at a time and for all keywords they've previously added to be hidden inputs on the form.

Here's my current code:

```
<form method="post" class="domain-form">
    <div class="domain-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" class="domain-input" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Type a keyword here...">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="button-link button-black getstarted" style="border-top-left-radius:0;border-bottom-left-radius:0;"><span>Add Keyword</span></button>
    <input type="hidden" id="domain" name="domain" value="<?php echo $domain; ?>">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
    foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $inputkeyword) {
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"keyword\" name=\"keyword\" value=\"$inputkeyword\">";
    }
}
?>

</form>
```

I'm getting an error stating `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `keyword[]`

Comment: you are passing a form variable and calling it as an array. do you have multiple keywords? then where it rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `name` structure. The name must have `[]` on it to create an array.

```
name="keyword[]"
```

otherwise it is a plain input and the duplicates overwrite.

This can be found in the documentation here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you should enter action attribute in form, name attribute of button & add name="keyword[]" in your input type text also like below then try**

```
<form method="post" action="" class="domain-form">

<input type="text" name="keyword[]" id="keyword" class="domain-input" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Type a keyword here...">

 <button type="submit" name="keyword" class="button-link button-black getstarted" style="border-top-left-radius:0;border-bottom-left-radius:0;"><span>Add Keyword</span></button>
```

Comment: Now i edit the answer, i forget to mention name="keyword[]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use to javascript to achieve this. just add an "add keyword" button for that input and put a click listener on it when the button is clicked you create and append the hidden input to the  DOM